# How to access URL Parameters within a service instead of controller in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

As the question state, what is the best way to find out what the query parameters are in a URL outside of the controller? I can see there is a $routeParams and $location service that appear to be services you can attach to a controller, but I want to make it such that when the application first initializes, the service fetches data from a service to initialize its contents. How could I access the parameters without going through a controller? Is this not a good practice?

From my understanding the Services initialize first, which is why I want to be able to fetch the data before the controllers are created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can inject the angular services (`$location` is one) into any of Angular's components - service, controller, directive, etc, and access the query string as an object with `$location.search()`.

Angular controllers are just for data-binding and shouldn't be concerned with anything else. You sound like you're worried about doing things outside of the controller, but really the opposite is true. A lot of people use the controller for things it isn't meant for.

It also seems relevant to your question that services are singletons and the single instance of them will be created when they are needed the first time. In other words, if you never inject one of your services, there is no instance of it.